# Invalid Inputs on POST request

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I'm receiving an invalid inputs error on my signup POST request on Postman. I've checked my User Model attributes but can't seem to find exactly which input(s) is/are being called invalid. Here is my model, controller, route. and app.js. Kindly take a look.

App

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const usersRoutes = require('./routes/users-routes');
const postsRoutes = require('./routes/posts-routes');
const HttpError = require('./models/http-error');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api/users', usersRoutes);
app.use('/api/posts', postsRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new HttpError('Could not find this route.', 404);
    throw error;
})

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  if (res.headerSent) {
    return next(error);
  }
  res.status(error.code || 500)
  res.json({ message: error.message || 'An unknown error occurred!' });
});

const connectUrl = 'hidden';

const connectConfig = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true
}

mongoose
    .connect(connectUrl, connectConfig)
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(5000);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

User model

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  avatarUrl: { type: String, required: true },
  posts: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Post' }]
});
```

Users controller

```
const signup = async (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return next(
      new HttpError('Invalid inputs passed, please check your data.', 422)
    );
  }
  const { username, email, password } = req.body;


  let existingUser
  try {
    existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: email })
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError('Signing up failed, please try again later.', 500);
    return next(error);
  }

  if (existingUser) {
    const error = new HttpError('User exists already, please login instead.', 422);
    return next(error);
  }

  const createdUser = new User({
    username,
    email,
    password,
    avatarUrl: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/406014/pexels-photo-406014.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260',
    posts: []
  });

  try {
    await createdUser.save();
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError('Signup failed, please try again.', 500);
    return next(error);
  }

  res.status(201).json({ user: createdUser.toObject({ getters: true })});
}
```

User routes

```
router.post(
  '/signup',
  [
    check('username').not().isEmpty(),
    check('email').normalizeEmail().isEmail(),
    check('password').isLength({ min: 6 })
  ],
  usersController.signup
);
```

Postman

[image]

Comment: `if (!errors.isEmpty()) {` is executed so you are getting that response. Can you print your `errors`??

Comment: Hey Subburaj. Here's what I got. Result {
  formatter: [Function: formatter],
  errors: [
    {
      value: undefined,
      msg: 'Invalid value',
      param: 'username',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      value: '@',
      msg: 'Invalid value',
      param: 'email',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      value: undefined,
      msg: 'Invalid value',
      param: 'password',
      location: 'body'
    }
  ]
}

Comment: It clearly states that some error is there. So if you solve those you wont get the `invalid response`

Comment: Whether  `req.body` is printing??

Comment: Right, but I'm not understanding why the value is undefined for username and password. I've tried different values to test and none are valid.

Comment: ```req.body``` isn't printing actually. I'm going to look into this. I appreciate your help btw.

Comment: Most probably you would missed that `bodyParser`

Comment: Can you show us your index.js (main file) code?

Comment: Hey SuleymanSah. I updated the post above to show app.js (main file).

Comment: So do you still get undefined req.body? Did you logged it before this line? `const errors = validationResult(req);`  Also tag me in this format @SuleymanSah so that I can get notification.

Comment: Kenneth can you also send a screenshot of the Headers in postman? You should have a `"Content-Type: application/json` header there

Comment: @SuleymanSah That was it! The ```"Content-Type: application/json``` box was unchecked. Checking the box got the code to work. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you using `body parser` in your middleware:

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

Comment: Hey Titus. Yes, I am using body-parser in my middleware. ```app.use(bodyParser.json());```

Comment: I think you don't have to download and install bodyParser, because use the code in my answer it's working fine, in there express using bodyparser too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @SuleymanSah for the answer (sorry, I don't know how to mark your comment above as the answer)

The issue was that the Headers box for `Content-Type: application/json` on Postman was unchecked. Checking the box solved the invalid inputs issue.